# Avoiding errors with \includexmp{pdfa-1b}. Any list of best practices and working example(s) with complete .XMP file(s)?

Tags: pdf-a, xmp

I am getting following error when trying to use some **pdfa-1b** stuff:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/lib
raries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (./chronosyschr.tex)) (./longtable.sty) (./arydshln.sty) (./xmpincl.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.274 \includexmp{pdfa-1b}

?
```

Code in my .tex file as follows:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% XMP data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xmpincl}

\providecommand{\xmpProducer}{LaTeX2e}
\providecommand{\xmpOrg}{MyOrg}
\providecommand{\xmpTitle}{\ttitle}
\providecommand{\xmpAuthor}{\tauthor, mymail@gmail.com}
\providecommand{\xmpKeywords}{\tkeywordsEn}

\includexmp{pdfa-1b}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% pdfInfo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pdfinfo{%
/Title    (\ttitle)
/Author   (\tauthor, mymail@gmail.com)
/Subject  (\ttitleEn)
/Keywords (\tkeywordsEn)
/ModDate  (\pdfcreationdate)
/Trapped  /False
}
```

XMP metadata examples (or *XMP predefined schemas*) are not readily available in documentation, apart from license.XMP, that works. But examples of actual usage and **best practices** with more complete metadata are missing.

And I am trying to use pdfa-1b.xmp file form GitHub repo: 
https://github.com/bencomp/pdfx-ext/blob/master/pdfa-1b.xmp
(since whatever was provided by our faculty does not compile; and dropping its content into https://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/xmp-metadata/free-xmp-validator/ turned *not valid*).

And all extensive documentation lacks basic working examples... Or perhaps just looking at wrong pdfa-1b documentation / packages...

Thank you in advance for any useful answers.

Comment: Please provide a complete Minimal non-Working Example (MnWE). A fragment of code, an obscurely-related subject and a rather confusing explanation is not a good basis on which to expect useful answers. Hope you may, but clarifying things would likely be a more productive strategy. See [this meta question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=3|0.6311) for some help on what's required. Why is 'EXAMPLE - .ZIP` capitalised and what does the question mean?

Comment: What, for example, are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to compile a **pdfa-1b** compliant PDF. Examples with valid XMP schemas are missing (except from the _license.xmp_). 
Some examples and best practices might be handy. Including explanation on how to include correct startingPage, endingPage, etc.

Comment: Problem solved thanks to @marijn. 
However I as still wondering if *ID* value in < ? xpacket ? > is supposed to be [auto-genereted or somehow provided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314231/is-id-value-in-xpacket-bits-included-in-pdfa-1b-xmp-auto-generated-or-shoul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xmpincl` package works with, e.g., the xmp file provided in the manual (see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xmpincl?lang=en, it is the easiest to copy the xmp from the end of the .dtx file).

However, the `pdfa-1b.xmp` file contains some conditionals with `@`, therefore you need to surrond the `\includexmp` with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. On my system for some reason the `\ifx \@empty` construct did not work (the else clause was executed), I replaced this in the xmp file with `\ifx \undefined` which did work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% XMP data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xmpincl}

\providecommand{\xmpProducer}{LaTeX2e}
\providecommand{\xmpOrg}{MyOrg}
\providecommand{\xmpTitle}{MyTitle}
\providecommand{\xmpAuthor}{MyAuthor, mymail@gmail.com}
\providecommand{\xmpKeywords}{MyKeywords}
\providecommand{\xmpSubject}{MySubject}
\providecommand{\xmpCreatorTool}{\pdftexbanner}
\providecommand{\convDate}{\pdfcreationdate}
\makeatletter
\includexmp{pdfa-1b}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% pdfInfo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pdfinfo{%
/Title    (MyTitle)
/Author   (MyAuthor, mymail@gmail.com)
/Subject  (MySubject)
/Keywords (MyKeywords)
/ModDate  (\pdfcreationdate)
/Trapped  /False
}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Snippet from the modified `pdfa-1b.xmp`:

```
\ifx\xmpJournalnumber\undefined\relax\else<prism:issn>\xmpJournalnumber</prism:issn>\fi
\ifx\xmpVolume\undefined\relax\else<prism:volume>\xmpVolume</prism:volume>\fi
\ifx\xmpIssue\undefined\relax\else<prism:number>\xmpIssue</prism:number>\fi
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: **Thank you.** Wrapping `\includexmp{pdfa-1b}` between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` removed error _missing $_ .

Moving forward I had to add some additional values with `\provide command`:

`\providecommand{\xmpAuthorURI}{}
\providecommand{\xmpJournalnumber}{}
\providecommand{\xmpVolume}{}
\providecommand{\xmpIssue}{}
\providecommand{\xmpCoverDisplayDate}{}
\providecommand{\xmpCoverDate}{}
\providecommand{\xmpJournaltitle}{}
\providecommand{\xmpFirstpage}{}
\providecommand{\xmpLastpage}{}
\providecommand{\xmpDoi}{}`

Comment: @ErikUšaj for the empty commands you can also use the modification as described in my answer: replace every occurrence of  `\@empty` in `pdfa-1b.xmp` by `\undefined`. This results in missing values being skipped (as is also intended by `\@empty` in the original `pdfa-1b.xmp`). When you do this once, you don't need to define `{}` commands in your LaTeX documents every time.

Comment: This approach doesn't work with LuaLaTeX, right?

Comment: @TheSodesa that's right, the package manual states (in the source code) that _Only pdflatex is supported by the xmpincl package_.